# acessing variables inside an enclosing scope, specifically BlahListeners

Tags: java, eclipse, listeners

I am working with the awt package, and because I feel that it is what I need, I am making a frame, then making components and containers that go inside that frame. To do that I am making classes that extend Component or (not quite there yet) Container or anything else that it comes up that I need. My issue is that I need to use MouseListeners and ComponentListeners, but I "can't access non-final variables within an enclosing scope." Now, A: It seems like it  needs to be static, not final, but i'll trust it. B: HOW CAN I DO THIS! Basically, I need to be able to access "this", but "this" is the new Listener, not the class. Does anybody know how to fix this, and/or an alternate way to do things? Thanks!

Comment: It would be *much* easier to help you if you'd show a minimal (but complete) piece of code demonstrating the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
ContainingClass.this.someMethod(); // Inside your Listener for example
```

ContainingClass and someMethod are just bogus values ;) You need to get out of the Listener scope if I did understand you correctly.

Comment: you don't need this syntax to call a method or access a member variable - that can be done directly (just call `someMethod()`)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misunderstood the question, so my previous answer is irrelevant.

You're asking about accessing non-final local variables from anonymous inner clases. This is not something Java permits, at the moment. In fact, implementing it would be somewhat hard.

If a variable is final, we can just take its value. Hopwever, if it's not final, we need to provide a piece of memory, potentially shared by multiple anonumous instances, that all of them can modify. This is quite a problem: where would that memory be allocated? How would you protect it in a multithreaded environemnt?

The usual approach is to use member variables to share writeable information between anonymous inner classes (not necessarily static members).

Comment: It's not that rare when you're using gwt/gxt or other frameworks like that.

Comment: Ya, but, It worked with Healthbar.this.blah(). It was absolutly fine